# Filter array of objects by array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

How to filter the following array with another array values?

```
  const GuideTabs = [
    { id: 0, label: 'Highlights', analyticsCategory: 'Highlights' },
    { id: 1, label: 'Labor & Employment', analyticsCategory: 'Labor & Employment' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Culture', analyticsCategory: 'Culture' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Holidays', analyticsCategory: 'Holidays' },
  ]
```

I want to filter this array with the following array to return only the existing data

```
 const gtabs = ['Culture, Holidays']
  const arr = GuideTabs.filter(function(item){
    return gtabs.indexOf(item.id) === -1
  })
```

But it returns all the 4 array item in GuideTabs all the time, But it should return 2,3 items from
GuideTabs array

```js
  const GuideTabs = [
    { id: 0, label: 'Highlights', analyticsCategory: 'Highlights' },
    { id: 1, label: 'Labor & Employment', analyticsCategory: 'Labor & Employment' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Culture', analyticsCategory: 'Culture' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Holidays', analyticsCategory: 'Holidays' },
  ]
  const gtabs = ['Culture, Holidays']
  const arr = GuideTabs.filter(function(item){
    return gtabs.indexOf(item.id) === -1
  })
  
  console.log(arr)
```

Comment: `const gtabs = ['Culture, Holidays']` this is an array with one element. I guess this should be `const gtabs = ['Culture', 'Holidays']`

Comment: `return gtabs.indexOf(item.label) != -1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
gtabs.includes(obj.label))
```

Because you are going to compare with `gTabs` that contain strings i.e `"Culture", "Holidays"`

```js
const GuideTabs = [
  { id: 0, label: "Highlights", analyticsCategory: "Highlights" },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Labor & Employment",
    analyticsCategory: "Labor & Employment",
  },
  { id: 2, label: "Culture", analyticsCategory: "Culture" },
  { id: 3, label: "Holidays", analyticsCategory: "Holidays" },
];

const gtabs = ["Culture", "Holidays"];

const result = GuideTabs.filter((obj) => gtabs.includes(obj.label));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` along with `filter` too.

```
const result = GuideTabs.filter((tab) => gtabs.some((guideTab) => guideTab === tab.label));
```